# Finding Cities within 'X' Kilometers (or Miles)

Tags: mysql, gis, coordinates, distance, coordinate-systems

This may or may not be clear, leave me a comment if I am off base, or you need more information.  Perhaps there is a solution out there already for what I want in PHP.

I am looking for a function that will add or subtract a distance from a longitude OR latitude value.

Reason: I have a database with all Latitudes and Longitudes in it and want to form a query to extract all cities within X kilometers (or miles).  My query would look something like this...

```
Select * From Cities Where (Longitude > X1 and Longitude < X2) And (Latitude > Y1 and Latitude < Y2)

 Where X1 = Longitude - (distance)
 Where X2 = Longitude + (distance)

 Where Y1 = Latitude - (distance)
 Where Y2 = Latitude + (distance)
```

I am working in PHP, with a MySql Database.

Open to any suggestions also! :)

Comment: you could always derive the function yourself... this seems like highschool-level calculus, or maybe even trig if you really simplify it...

Comment: You'd think so, but the Earth is not a perfect sphere, and the variation between 1 degree longitude at the equator and 1 degree longitude elsewhere is surprisingly large. It's definitely not as simple as one would hope!

Comment: (see my answer below :))

Comment: @ Mike, you can't just add a scalar distance to get a single new longitude and lattitude. You need to specify angles as well due to curvature of the Earth. You said you wanted to find cities with X kilometers, my solution does that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a MySQL query that will do exactly what you want. Keep in mind things like this are approximations generally, as the earth is not perfectly spherical nor does this take into account mountains, hills, valleys, etc.. We use this code on [AcademicHomes.com](http://www.academichomes.com) with PHP and MySQL, it returns records within $radius miles of $latitude, $longitude.

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT
    * 
FROM
    your_table
WHERE
    (
        (69.1 * (latitude - " . $latitude . ")) * 
        (69.1 * (latitude - " . $latitude . "))
    ) + ( 
        (69.1 * (longitude - " . $longitude . ") * COS(" . $latitude . " / 57.3)) * 
        (69.1 * (longitude - " . $longitude . ") * COS(" . $latitude . " / 57.3))
    ) < " . pow($radius, 2) . " 
ORDER BY 
    (
        (69.1 * (latitude - " . $latitude . ")) * 
        (69.1 * (latitude - " . $latitude . "))
    ) + ( 
        (69.1 * (longitude - " . $longitude . ") * COS(" . $latitude . " / 57.3)) * 
        (69.1 * (longitude - " . $longitude . ") * COS(" . $latitude . " / 57.3))
    ) ASC");
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking Keith, what is your index setup for, on this query?  This works great, but its scanning every row in the DB with keys on Lat/Long

Comment: Hey Mike, 

If performance matters, I set up an INDEX on 'latitude' and an INDEX on 'longitude', and I tweak the above query by using BETWEEN clauses to restrict the query to a smaller subset of records. Add in something like: 

WHERE 
 latitude BETWEEN 
   $latitude - ($radius / 70) AND 
   $latitude + ($radius / 70) AND 
 longitude BETWEEN 
   $longitude - ($radius / 70) AND 
   $longitude + ($radius / 70)  
... 

This allows the database to use the indexes on latitude and longitude. 

The constant 70 is because the max distance 1 degree of latitude or longitude ever spans is about 70 miles.

Comment: P.S. On our aging development server with a table with 2.9 million cities/towns around the world in it, the query times change from: 

Without indexes on latitude/longitude: 10.9 seconds

With indexes on latitude/longitude: 0.52 seconds

Comment: Use spacial indexes to quickly locate cities nearby.  Much faster than ordinary indexes for this kind of work.

Comment: Hey Keith, I missed this post (since seeing your original answer that I used - which works great).  Our DB now has about 2.8~ mill records, and came back to add this:   $longitude_rectangle1 = $longitude - $distance / abs(cos(deg2rad($latitude))*69);  $longitude_rectangle2 = $longitude + $distance / abs(cos(deg2rad($latitude))*69);
  $latitude_rectangle1 = $latitude - ($distance/69);
  $latitude_rectangle2 = $latitude + ($distance/69);

I used those for the in-betweens - does it look about right?

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: If you have, somewhere, a list of all of the cities in the world along with their lat. and long. values, you can do a lookup. In this case, see my first link below for the formula to calculate the width of one longitudinal degree at latitude [image] :

[image]

Honestly, the complications behind this problem are such that you'd be far better off using a service such as Google Maps to get your data. Specifically, the Earth is not a perfect sphere, and the distance between two degrees varies as you are closer to / further from the equator.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system for examples of what I mean, and check out [the Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/).

Comment: that's essentially the function I was proposing he derive.  I don't think the earth's slight asphericalness will matter over any reasonable distance... IIRC, the difference in the distance between the poles and across the equator is like 50 miles, which is nothing in earth-sized terms.

Comment: It makes a big difference when calculating position on the surface, however.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many cities you are including, you can precompute the list. We do this here for an internal application where an inaccuracy of +100m is too much for our setup. It works by having a two key table of location1, location2, distance. We can then pull back locations x distance from location1 very quickly.

Also since the calcs can be done offline, it doesn't impact the running of the system. Users also get faster results.

Answer (score 1):

I Tried using the above code, and the answers were off by too much when the distance between points was in the 20-30 mile range, and I'm ok with a few miles of error.  Talked with a mapping buddy of mine and we came up with this one instead.  The code is python, but you can translate it pretty easily.  In order to avoid the constant conversion to radians, I redid my database, converting the lat/lng points from degrees to Radians.  The nice part about this is that the largest part of the math is mostly done once.

```
ra = 3963.1906 # radius @ equator in miles, change to km  if you want distance in km
rb = 3949.90275  # radius @ poles in miles, change to km  if you want distance in km
ra2 = ra * ra
rb2 = rb * rb

phi = self.lat

big_ol_constant = (math.pow(ra2*math.cos(phi), 2) + pow(rb2*math.sin(phi), 2))/ (pow(ra*math.cos(phi), 2) + pow(rb*math.sin(phi), 2))

sqlWhere = "%(distance)g > sqrt((power(lat - %(lat)g,2) + power(lng-%(lng)g,2)) * %(big_ol_constant)g)" % {
    'big_ol_constant': big_ol_constant, 'lat': self.lat, 'lng': self.lng, 'distance': distance}

# This is the Django portion of it, where the ORM kicks in.  sqlWhere is what you would put after the WHERE part of your SQL Query.
qs = ZipData.objects.extra(where=[sqlWhere]);
```

Seems to be very accurate when distance apart is small, and within 10 miles or so as the distance grows to 200 miles, (of course by then, you have issues with "as the crow flies" vs "paved roads").

Here is the model ZipData that I mention above.

```
class ZipData(models.Model):
    zipcode = ZipCodeField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name="ZipCode", primary_key=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=False, blank=False)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    lat = models.FloatField(null=False, blank=False)
    lng = models.FloatField(null=False, blank=False)
```

An extra note, is that you can gets LOTS of geo data related to postal codes at [GeoNames.org](http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/) and they even have some webservice APIs you can use as well.

Comment: this is great Mark0978. Do you have the complete code or django-app that you can share as a plug & play module?

Comment: I've now included the model object.  You can email me my username  @gmail.com and I'll send you the files that make up that app, but I wouldn't consider them a reusable app.

Answer (score 0):

There are many (bad options)

- Calculate the distance using the mathematical formula (treat X1-X2 and Y1-Y2) as vectors.
- Create a lookup table in advance with all the combinations and keep the distances.
- Consider using a GIS-specific extension of MySQL. Here is [one article](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/gis-with-mysql.html) I found about this.

Answer (score 0):

lessthandot.com actually has 3 different ways to do this.  you'll have to scroll through the blogs a little but they're there.
http://blogs.lessthandot.com/

Answer (score 0):

The function below is from the [nerddinner](http://nerddinner.com)'s (ASP.NET MVC sample application [available on codeplex](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/)) database (MSSQL).

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[DistanceBetween] (@Lat1 as real,
                @Long1 as real, @Lat2 as real, @Long2 as real)
RETURNS real
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @dLat1InRad as float(53);
SET @dLat1InRad = @Lat1 * (PI()/180.0);
DECLARE @dLong1InRad as float(53);
SET @dLong1InRad = @Long1 * (PI()/180.0);
DECLARE @dLat2InRad as float(53);
SET @dLat2InRad = @Lat2 * (PI()/180.0);
DECLARE @dLong2InRad as float(53);
SET @dLong2InRad = @Long2 * (PI()/180.0);

DECLARE @dLongitude as float(53);
SET @dLongitude = @dLong2InRad - @dLong1InRad;
DECLARE @dLatitude as float(53);
SET @dLatitude = @dLat2InRad - @dLat1InRad;
/* Intermediate result a. */
DECLARE @a as float(53);
SET @a = SQUARE (SIN (@dLatitude / 2.0)) + COS (@dLat1InRad)
                 * COS (@dLat2InRad)
                 * SQUARE(SIN (@dLongitude / 2.0));
/* Intermediate result c (great circle distance in Radians). */
DECLARE @c as real;
SET @c = 2.0 * ATN2 (SQRT (@a), SQRT (1.0 - @a));
DECLARE @kEarthRadius as real;
/* SET kEarthRadius = 3956.0 miles */
SET @kEarthRadius = 6376.5;        /* kms */

DECLARE @dDistance as real;
SET @dDistance = @kEarthRadius * @c;
return (@dDistance);
END
```

I am guessing this could be helpful.

Comment: The earth doesn't have a constant radius - this will get you close, but (at least for my previous application) not close enough. If you're not worried about a few (up to a few hundred) miles' difference, this would be a good way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pythagoras' Theorem to calculate the proximity of two pairs of lat/lon points.

If you have two locations (Alpha and Beta) you can calculate their distance apart with:

```
SQRT( POW(Alpha_lat - Beta_lat,2) + POW(Alpha_lon - Beta_lon,2) )
```

Comment: For short distances this would be nice but our planet is not flat

Answer (score 0):

Using the setup from the following URL, Ive built the query below. (Please note Im using codeIgnitor to query the database)

http://howto-use-mysql-spatial-ext.blogspot.com/2007/11/using-circular-area-selection.html

```
function getRadius($point="POINT(-29.8368 30.9096)", $radius=2)
{
    $km = 0.009;
    $center = "GeomFromText('$point')";
    $radius = $radius*$km;
    $bbox = "CONCAT('POLYGON((',
        X($center) - $radius, ' ', Y($center) - $radius, ',',
        X($center) + $radius, ' ', Y($center) - $radius, ',',
        X($center) + $radius, ' ', Y($center) + $radius, ',',
        X($center) - $radius, ' ', Y($center) + $radius, ',',
        X($center) - $radius, ' ', Y($center) - $radius, '
    ))')";

    $query = $this->db->query("
    SELECT id, AsText(latLng) AS latLng, (SQRT(POW( ABS( X(latLng) - X({$center})), 2) + POW( ABS(Y(latLng) - Y({$center})), 2 )))/0.009 AS distance
    FROM crime_listing
    WHERE Intersects( latLng, GeomFromText($bbox) )
    AND SQRT(POW( ABS( X(latLng) - X({$center})), 2) + POW( ABS(Y(latLng) - Y({$center})), 2 )) < $radius
    ORDER BY distance
        ");

    if($query->num_rows()>0){
        return($query->result());
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. This is a spatial query. Use [MySQL's built-in spatial extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159255/what-is-the-ideal-data-type-to-use-when-storing-latitude-longitudes-in-a-mysql) to store the latitude-longitude coordinate data in the [native MySQL geometry column type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-spatial-values.html). Then use the [Distance](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/functions-that-test-spatial-relationships-between-geometries.html#function_distance) function to query for points that are within a specified distance of one another.

Disclaimer: this is based on reading the documentation, I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: From the top of the page you linked:

Currently, MySQL does not implement these functions according to the specification. Those that are implemented return the same result as the corresponding MBR-based functions. This includes functions in the following list other than Distance() and Related().

Comment: @Mark0978 The page does contain that disclaimer, but in my answer I'm recommending the `Distance` function. The disclaimer, as quoted in your comment, does not apply to the `Distance` function. Therefore the disclaimer is not relevant to my answer.