# how to sort rows by a distance from a given point, mysql?

Tags: mysql, geospatial, distance, spatial

I'm trying to get 100 points from my table with a lowest distance to a given point.

I'm using

```
SELECT *, GLENGTH(
            LINESTRINGFROMWKB(
              LINESTRING(
                ASBINARY(
                  POINTFROMTEXT("POINT(40.4495 -79.988)")
                ),
                ASBINARY(pt)
              )
            )
          )
 AS `distance` FROM `ip_group_city` ORDER BY distance LIMIT 100
```

(Yeah, that's painful. I've just googled it. I have no idea how to measure distance in MySQL correctly)

It takes very long time for execute. `EXPLAIN` says that there are no `possible_keys`.

I created a `SPATIAL` index on the `pt` column:

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX sp_index ON  ip_group_city (pt);
```

Though I don't really know how to use it correctly. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you don't have WHERE clause therefore no affected index. I think you should improve this query by add using MBR_ (MySQL 5.0 or later) or ST_ functions (MySQL 5.6 or later).
Something like:

```
SELECT *, GLENGTH(
            LINESTRINGFROMWKB(
              LINESTRING(
                ASBINARY(
                  POINTFROMTEXT("POINT(40.4495 -79.988)")
                ),
                ASBINARY(pt)
              )
            )
          )
 AS `distance` 
FROM `ip_group_city` 
WHERE
MBRWithin(
        pt, -- your point
        GeomFromText('Polygon( -- your line (in polygon format) from pt to target point 
                        (
                            #{bound.ne.lat} #{bound.ne.lng}, --North East Lat - North East Long
                            #{bound.ne.lat} #{bound.sw.lng}, --North East Lat - South West Long
                            #{bound.sw.lat} #{bound.sw.lng}, --
                            #{bound.sw.lat} #{bound.ne.lng},
                            #{bound.ne.lat} #{bound.ne.lng}
                        )
                    )')
      )
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [great circle equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) to do these types of calculations in the past.  I'm not sure how the performance compares but it might be worth trying it and comparing.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574691/mysql-great-circle-distance-haversine-formula) is a good SO post that goes over how to do it in MySQL.

Comment: it does not use spatial at all, too... what is it (spatial index) for, then?

Comment: Yours is the only type of solution that would potentially use the spatial index.  I'm just suggesting another method worth trying to see how the performance compares.

Comment: oh. I started with a method, similar to yours, and got a lot worst perfomance

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at these questions:

- [Finding Cities within 'X' Kilometers (or Miles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808963/finding-cities-within-x-kilometers-or-miles)

Comment: it's not sorting and it does not use spatial at all