# Get list of latitude and longitude within the specified radius

Tags: java

I have the current location stored inside 2 double values. In my database, I have list of locations, each with latitude and longitude. How do I get the list of locations which is (let's say) 3 kilometers from my current location?

For example, this is the data inside my database:

```
Location | Latitude | Longitude
AAA      |  1.555   | 0.56767
BBB      | 2.33     | 3.444
CCC      | 1.000    | 2.44
```

What kind of calculation should I do?

Comment: This question, of calculating a great-circle distance between Earth surface points, is nearly an FAQ here on SO.  Before calculating, review some of the good Qs and As knocking around hereabouts.

Comment: You can find the answer previously answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808963/finding-cities-within-x-kilometers-or-miles