# Correct datatype for latitude and longitude? (in activerecord)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, types

Should I store latitude and longitude as strings or floats (or something else)?

(I'm using activerecord / ruby on rails, if that matters).

Update:

Mysql in development and postgresql in production (why does it matter?)

Comment: Mysql in development and postgresql in production (why does it matter?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the ideal data type to use when storing latitude / longitudes in a MySQL database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159255/what-is-the-ideal-data-type-to-use-when-storing-latitude-longitudes-in-a-mysql)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you need to do more complex geographical calculations, you can investigate [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) for Postgresql or [MySQL Spatial Extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/6.0/en/spatial-extensions.html) for MySQL.  Otherwise, a float (double precision might be a good idea) should work.

**Edit:** It looks like the [GeoRuby](https://github.com/nofxx/georuby) library includes a Rails extension for working with the spatial/GIS extensions for both of the aforementioned databases.

Comment: There's another more popular library you could try. [geocoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) or checkout [github](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder)

Answer (score 158):

This is what I use:

```
add_column :table_name, :lat, :decimal, {:precision=>10, :scale=>6}
add_column :table_name, :lng, :decimal, {:precision=>10, :scale=>6}
```

Comment: The value should be within interval (-180, 180), right?  Why your scale is not 7?

Comment: From the Google Maps documentation: "To keep the storage space required for your table at a minimum, you can specify that the lat and lng attributes are floats of size (10,6)"

Answer (score 22):

If you're not using a spatially-enabled database, Google Maps [recommends](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax.html) using floats of size (10,6).  That gives you 6 digits after the decimal - if you want more precision, you can adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using floats, although it doesn't really make that much of a difference.  Floats are easier to do calculations on if you ever desire that in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you want Lat/Long stored in the largest float type you have. At some latitudes (eg: near the equator) very small changes in longitude can equate to large differences in terms of surface distance.

I suppose if it is a field which you won't ever want to do any math on, you could use a string. I'd avoid that though.

Answer (score -3):

Since they're fixed precision, you should convert and store as integer for a significant performance improvement.

(SEE http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL)