# Ruby-On-Rails and PostgreSQL - Decimal error causing an import of a CSV file to fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm having a big problem with Ruby-On-Rails and PostgreSQL. I'm using [geokit gem](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails) to locate my Store model. This morning before I added geokit gem, my model had a longitude and a latitude column, both of `:string` type. After adding the gem, I realized that I needed my column to be `:float` type so I created the migration and modified my columns. I then added all my records (from a csv file) to the database.

Everything seemed to work well because I could locate my records from an address thanks to geokit. Then during my tests, I realized that one of my records didn't have all the decimal places in its coordinates. I then thought that it had to come from float which I know how to create problems so many decimal places.

I recreated a migration to transform my colones into `:decimal` like [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196174/correct-datatype-for-latitude-and-longitude-in-activerecord).
Since then, nothing gets imported, I have relaunched the parsing of the csv and all my records are now only 1 decimal (example: 0.2,4.1) I wanted to go backwards but that's impossible. Now that I use float or decimal in my database it's the same: it's impossible to have more than one number after the comma.

I created a new project and relaunch, nothing to do I can't have more than 1 decimal. I'm worried about having created a bug, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, the error came from my file, it used ',' instead of ''.'

Comment: I would use Postgis which provides native geolocation column types for postgres instead of decimal. It gives far better performance for geolocation based queries. http://ngauthier.com/2013/08/postgis-and-rails-a-simple-approach.html