# How many significant digits should I store in my database for a GPS coordinate?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, gps, rdbms

I have in my MySQL database both longitude and latitude coordinates (GPS data).

It's currently stored as:

```
column     type
------------------------
geolat     decimal(10,6)
geolng     decimal(10,6)
```

**Question:**  Do I really need a data type as large as `decimal(10,6)` to properly store coordinate data?

Since I have a combined index on the longitude and latitude, this index size is huge. If I can make it smaller without compromising anything, that would be great.

Comment: Also, I do realize that MySQL has a SPATIAL plugin - but my webhost does not have that installed unfortunately, so that's not an option (in case anyone recommends it)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Great first question.

Comment: And don't forget, you will also need to know the geographic coordinate system, or else your latitude/longitude values are useless.  Most GPS units these days will give you answers in WGS84, but you should probably confirm the data before you save it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the ideal data type to use when storing latitude / longitudes in a MySQL database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159255/what-is-the-ideal-data-type-to-use-when-storing-latitude-longitudes-in-a-mysql)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/55600320/1766831

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[WGS84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) datum are usually given as coordinates in a fully decimal notation, usually with 5 decimal places, so for latitude (-90 to +90) you could use decimal(7, 5) (-90.00000 to 90.00000), for longitude you could use decimal(8, 5) (-180.00000 to 180.00000).

.00001 [gives an precision of around a meter at the equator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject_Geographical_coordinates#Precision)

The [DECIMAL/NUMERIC data type is a fixed precision scaled integer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) and both positive and negative parts of the range are always available - they do not affect the precision or scale (there is obviously storage required for it, but you don't get a choice about that for DECIMAL)

Comment: Does the sign (positive/negative) not take up space? meaning, wouldn't "-90.12345" take up 8 digital and not 7

Comment: Yes, it takes up space in the database, but the space required in the database for a given DECIMAL specification always allows a sign.  I'm not familiar with the internal storage requirements of MySQL, but for SQL Server, a decimal takes 5 bytes (1-9 digits)/9 bytes (10-19 digits)/13 bytes (20-28 digits) /17 bytes (29-38 digits) depending on digits of precision specified (it is independent of scale, obviously).

Comment: Google Maps operates on 6 decimal places. Zoom in on your house, right click it on the map, then choose "Center on this position". Click the link button just outside the map, top left side, then find the GPS coordinates in the link URL. It was 6 decimals when I tried it.

Comment: If your source always gives you 6 decimal places of precision then you're ok with a field that accepts precision specifications. But, be careful storing from a source that has less precision than you have specified. I your source gives you low precision data like ".5872" and you store store this in a precision field with 6 decimal places you will get ".587200" which looks like a high precision number. If your sources have different levels of precision store it in a character field.

Answer (score 17):

It depends on the accuracy of the survey you are conducting. In general:

- The **6 decimal** places represent accuracy **for ~ 10 cm**
- The 7 decimal places for                    ~ 1 cm
- The 13 decimal places - accuracy for an atom structure...

Therefore, unless very precise studies i.e. for tectonic plates movements, **the use of 6 digits should be enough.**

---

Here is the copy of the [full answer from **whuber** (GIS stack overflow):](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude)

**Accuracy** is the tendency of your measurements to agree with the true values. **Precision** is the degree to which your measurements pin down an actual value. The question is about an interplay of accuracy and precision.

As a general principle, you don't need much more **precision** in recording your measurements than there is accuracy built into them. Using too much precision can mislead people into believing the accuracy is greater than it really is.

Generally, when you degrade precision--that is, use fewer decimal places--you can lose some accuracy. But how much? It's good to know that the meter was originally defined (by the French, around the time of their revolution when they were throwing out the old systems and zealously replacing them by new ones) so that ten million of them would take you from the equator to a pole. That's 90 degrees, so one degree of latitude covers about 10^7/90 = 111,111 meters. ("About," because the meter's length has changed a little bit in the meantime. But that doesn't matter.) Furthermore, a degree of longitude (east-west) is about the same or less in length than a degree of latitude, because the circles of latitude shrink down to the earth's axis as we move from the equator towards either pole. Therefore, it's always safe to figure that the sixth decimal place in one decimal degree has 111,111/10^6 = about 1/9 meter = about 4 inches of precision.

Accordingly, if your accuracy needs are, say, give or take 10 meters, than 1/9 meter is nothing: you lose essentially no accuracy by using six decimal places. If your accuracy need is sub-centimeter, then you need at least seven and probably eight decimal places, but more will do you little good.

**Thirteen decimal places** will pin down the location to 111,111/10^13 = about 1 angstrom, around half the thickness of a small atom.

Using these ideas we can construct a table of what each digit in a decimal degree signifies:

- The **sign** tells us whether we are north or south, east or west on
  the globe.
- A nonzero **hundreds digit** tells us we're using longitude, not latitude!
- The **tens digit** gives a position to about 1,000 kilometers. It gives us useful information about what continent or ocean we are on.
- The **units digit** (one decimal degree) gives a position up to 111 kilometers (60 nautical miles, about 69 miles). It can tell us
  roughly what large state or country we are in.
- The **first decimal** place is worth up to 11.1 km: it can distinguish the position of one
  large city from a neighboring large city.
- The **second decimal** place is
  worth up to 1.1 km: it can separate one village from the next.
- The
  third decimal place is worth up to 110 m: it can identify a large
  agricultural field or institutional campus.
- The **fourth decimal** place
  is worth up to 11 m: it can identify a parcel of land. It is
  comparable to the typical accuracy of an uncorrected GPS unit with no
  interference.
- The **fifth decimal** place is worth up to 1.1 m: it
  distinguish trees from each other. Accuracy to this level with
  commercial GPS units can only be achieved with differential
  correction.
- The **sixth decimal** place is worth up to 0.11 m: you can
  use this for laying out structures in detail, for designing
  landscapes, building roads. It should be more than good enough for
  tracking movements of glaciers and rivers. This can be achieved by
  taking painstaking measures with GPS, such as differentially
  corrected GPS.
- The **seventh decimal** place is worth up to 11 mm: this
  is good for much surveying and is near the limit of what GPS-based
  techniques can achieve.
- The **eighth decimal** place is worth up to 1.1
  mm: this is good for charting motions of tectonic plates and
  movements of volcanoes. Permanent, corrected, constantly-running GPS
  base stations might be able to achieve this level of accuracy.
- The
  **ninth decimal** place is worth up to 110 microns: we are getting into
  the range of microscopy. For almost any conceivable application with
  earth positions, this is overkill and will be more precise than the
  accuracy of any surveying device.
- **Ten or more decimal** places
  indicates a computer or calculator was used and that no attention was
  paid to the fact that the extra decimals are useless. Be careful,
  because unless you are the one reading these numbers off the device,
  this can indicate low quality processing!

Answer (score 4):

I've always worked with six digits after the decimal.  I used to do GIS work under a military contract and this was sufficient.

Comment: So, are you saying that I could change it to "decimal(6,6)" and be alright?

Comment: But as Jonathan notes, it really does depend on how precise you want.  From my understanding, the six digit precision got us down to somewhere around +/- 1 meter.  This was important because we were keeping track of bunkers full of chemical weapons.

Comment: I believe the "10" is the size of the whole field, isn't it?  You will need to accommodate  +/- xxx.xxxxxx for longitude and +/- xx.xxxxxx for latitude.

Comment: This is for a real estate application where we want to store the location of your houses/homes. So it doesn't need to be as accurate as +/- 1 meter. Something like +/- 10 meters would probably be acceptable

Comment: Whoops, you're correct. Decimal(10,6) means - 10 is the size of the whole field, 6 is the # of digits after the decimal point. As such, do you happen to know how much precision decimal(9,5) might give ... or where I could find out

Comment: +/- 10 meters is pretty big - approx 65ft - when rendering on a map, you might find your house showing up in the middle of the street.

Comment: @Steve, it looks like I only need 5 digits to have 1 meter of accuracy. Does this look correct to you? -->  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees

Comment: I defer to Cade Roux's comment, above.  We, too, were using the WGS84 datum.  Perhaps our resolution was a bit higher than 1 m.

You will want to ensure that you are using the same projection/datum information for all of your geospatial data.  WGS84 is a very common standard.  I have been bitten more than once by a customer providing data that was based on different projection/datum parameters than what I was using.

Comment: @Steve Elmer, So the marker shows up in the middle of the street. Is that really an issue to the end user? They're going to be looking around for the house anyways. If those unnecessary digits increase page rendering by a couple of seconds, that would be more important to the end user than the accuracy of the rendered marker.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that it's easier to reduce data than it is to increase data. Usually, increasing data accuracy isn't even possible short of remeasuring. And remeasuring comes at a cost. Knowing nothing else of your situation or the industry, I would say capture as much data/specificity as possible.

The data that you actually use can be culled from this set. If you end up needing a higher degree of specificity, you can always recalculate without remeasuring.

Also, I'm not sure that indexing raw data is the best thing to do since it isn't a discrete set of elements. Creating a table of less accurate/smaller data points would make the indexes much smaller.

Comment: *Always* ask this sort of question when thinking about storing data: What will it be used for?  What precision/range/whatever is needed to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

if this is for real estate do you really have so many houses that 2 bytes saved per row is going to be that noticeable? I'd keep as much precision as possible unless there was a good reason not to.

Comment: I'm more concerned about the size of my index since I have a combined index on both the longitude and latitude. So right now, my index size is decimal(10,6) + decimal(10,6) in size. Which is very large for an index.

Comment: was going to reply with spatial indexing - but noticed your comment saying you can't use it, hence why you are having these problems.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how precise you want your locatability to be. Obviously the larger the more precise, and the smaller the more broad your results will be. I'd suggest keeping your values larger, as it isn't really much data anyway.

Comment: This is only to store geo-data for house/home location (real estate app). So it doesn't need to be super accurate but close.

Answer (score 0):

The regular GGA sentance in a NMEA Lat/lon output is only 3decimal places roughly 10m resolution at the equator. Some brands add a custom extra digit to give 1m.

4 digit deg.mm mm/1000 is also common.

If you are using high end precision RTK-GPS you might need more places to get mm precision

Answer (score 0):

You can also try storing (and/or working with) your coordinates in different units.  One project I worked on, all of our coordinates were in milliarcseconds stored as longs (maybe ints, it's been a couple years).  This was done partially for speed and for storage space (this was an embedded system).  But the same logic could apply here.

Answer (score 0):

If all coordinates are in a specific area, fix some central point (i.e. average current points and round to get a number you can say out loud) and then store coordinates as relative to this point. That way you can probably skip the first 2-4 most significant digits which makes for big savings. But remember to handle this data only via a Class or VIEW that gives back true WGS84 coords.