# How to decode the TCP buffer data

Tags: node.js, tcp, gprs

I am trying to write a tcp server to get the data from Heacent 908 GPS tracker. After establishing the connection from the tracker I am getting the following buffer output.

```
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 06 64 be 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 06 64 be 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 06 64 be 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 06 64 be 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 06 64 be 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 06 64 be 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 06 64 be 0d 0a>
```

I am not sure how to decode this data into proper readable format.

Note: Off course I have tried to reach the manufacture but they are not responding at all.

What type of possible encoding formats are there for TCP protocol?

On next day I got data like this

```
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 07 75 37 0d 0a> 
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 07 75 37 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 07 75 37 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 07 75 37 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 07 75 37 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 07 75 37 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 07 75 37 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 07 75 37 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 07 75 37 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 08 8d c0 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 08 8d c0 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 08 8d c0 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 08 8d c0 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 08 8d c0 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 08 8d c0 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 08 8d c0 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 08 8d c0 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 08 8d c0 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 08 8d c0 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 08 8d c0 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 08 8d c0 0d 0a>

<Buffer 78 78 1f 12 0e 02 14 13 01 14 c8 03 5f a6 50 07 f7 f8 c1 32 35 39 01 9a 04 0f a2 00 b0 5a 00 1a 9b 7a 0d 0a>
<Buffer 78 78 1f 12 0e 02 14 13 01 1e c8 03 5f ad bc 07 f7 f0 76 41 35 40 01 9a 04 0f a2 00 b0 5a 00 1b b6 31 0d 0a>
```

Something is being changed but not sure what is it...

Comment: From the manufacturer's PDF (http://www.heacent.com/download/Heacent%20gps%20munual(908).pdf) I guess  what you're asking about is the protocol used for "online realtime tracking" which they suggest you to use with their own service.  So you want to write your own server which accepts data from this device instead of using the manufacturer's service, correct?

Comment: Yes correct! I want to use my own for personal use!

Comment: OK.  They also publish a protocol guide but it isn't clear that it explains what you've written above: http://www.heacent.com/download%5CGPS%20protocol(Heacent).pdf

Comment: Yes gone through it but its making no sense at all :S

Comment: @coure2011 Did you get to convert the information in a readable format?

Answer (score 8):

You ask what possible encoding formats there are for TCP.  That's a bit of an odd question: there are an unbounded number of encoding formats using TCP as the underlying protocol.  But no matter, we can try to figure out this one!

You've posted some sample messages.  Let's see if we can translate them:

```
byte  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
rev  17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
----------------------------------------------------------
hex  78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 06 64 be 0d 0a
text  x  x \r -- -- -- --  1    --  H  B -- --  d -- \r \n
dec        13  1  3    17                 0 6 100    13 10
be32       [218170247] [288432262]       [   419006]
----------------------------------------------------------
hex  78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 07 75 37 0d 0a
text                                        --  u  7
dec                                         7 117 55
be32                                     [   488759]
---------------------------------------------------------- 
hex  78 78 0d 01 03 87 11 31 20 86 48 42 00 08 8d c0 0d 0a
text                                        -- -- --
dec                                         8 141
be32                                     [   560576]
----------------------------------------------------- byte 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
hex  78 78 1f 12 0e 02 14 13 01 14 c8 03 5f a6 50 07 f7 f8 c1 32 35 39 01 9a 04 0f a2 00 b0 5a 00 1a 9b 7a 0d 0a
text       -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  _ --  P -- -- -- --  2  5  9 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- xx --  z \r \n
---------------------------------------------------------- 
hex  78 78 1f 12 0e 02 14 13 01 1e c8 03 5f ad bc 07 f7 f0 76 41 35 40 01 9a 04 0f a2 00 b0 5a 00 1b b6 31 0d 0a
text                                           --       -- --  A  5  @                         -- xx --  1
```

Some potentially interesting facts:

- Starts with "xx\r\01" which more or less seems like a possible header.  But later messages start with "xx" and something else.  Anyway, given that NMEA has a prefix of "GP" I wouldn't be shocked if these devices used "xx" for "something that's not NMEA."
- Has "HB" in the middle, which could mean "heartbeat" since this is repeating, perhaps waiting for a reply from the server.
- Ends with "\r\n" which is a common line ending (on Windows in particular), though the rest doesn't appear to be entirely textual.
- The earlier messages are 18 bytes long and the later ones 36 bytes.  A guess would be the short ones are status updates or heartbeats and the long ones are actual location information.  36 bytes is enough if we figure:

  - 4 byte latitude: 24 bits if you pinch ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947481/how-many-significant-digits-should-i-store-in-my-database-for-a-gps-coordinate)), 25-32 bits more likely
  - 4 byte longitude: same as latitude
  - 6 byte timestamp: 39 bits if using epoch time with centiseconds, 32/48/64 bits more likely
  - 2 byte altitude: I suspect this device doesn't publish altitude at all, given some of the docs

So I think what is going on is that these messages you see are just the device "pinging" the server and waiting for a response.  What sort of response?  Well, you could try to brute force it, but far, far easier would be to set up a bridge in your program that takes whatever it receives from the device, sends it to the manufacturer's server, and does the same thing in reverse for the responses to the device.  This way you will quickly be able to gather a corpus of valid messages which will be very helpful if we really do need to reverse engineer this thing.  Or if you're lucky it will turn out to use some standard protocol like [NMEA](http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm) after negotiating the initial session.

Edit: now that you've given us more messages from the device, we can see that it does seem to send something else with variable content.  Maybe that's the location data, but I don't have time to try to reverse engineer it right now.  One idea is to physically move the unit from west to east or north to south and capture the messages it sends during that time, to try to isolate which parts of the messages are the longitude and which are the latitude (and perhaps timestamp too).

I think it's fairly clear that the first two bytes are "xx" as a header, and the last two are "\r\n" as a terminator.  That leaves 32 bytes of payload in the longer messages, all of which appears to be binary data.

Comment: man!!! why stackoverlow not allow to upvote multiple time :). Thanks a lot for this investigation. You have provided me a lot of information. Will study more based on your investigation.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Thank for this information, It's really usefull. I'm facing the same problem as "coure". The only doubt I've is, there would be a method to do the same you did but with code? I've already tried multiples types of decoding `utf8`, `utf16`, `ucs2` and all in [this library](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite/wiki/Supported-Encodings) support, do you know where can I look to get a readable output?

Answer (score 4):

It's the GT06 protocol and you can find it's specs here:

- http://www.traccar.org/devices/
- http://www.traccar.org/docs/protocol.jsp
- https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/sqtkulcj51zkria/GT06_GPS_Tracker_Communication_Protocol_v1.8.1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
client.on('data', (buffer) => {
  const decodedData = buffer.toString('utf8')
  console.log(decodedData)
})
```