# NSUserDefaults and using setobject method to store CLLocationCoordinate2D error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, cllocationcoordinate2d

I found the answer to this question here: [Store CLLocationCoordinate2D to NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910612/store-cllocationcoordinate2d-to-nsuserdefaults). And the code is written in Objective C. I understand, for the most part, what is happening with the code in that link. However, it is difficult for me to translate the syntax over to Swift. And I think it would be helpful for others to have this translation as well.

Just to reiterate the error, it is: `Cannot invoke 'setObject' with an argument list of type (CLLocationCoordinate2D, forKey: String!)`. And here is the syntax that is causing this problem:

```
let mapAnnotations = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let newCoordinate = self.mapView.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: self.mapView)
var title: String! = ""
self.mapAnnotations.setObject(newCoordinate, forKey: title) //the error is here
self.mapAnnotations.synchronize()
```

Comment: Read the Apple documentation on `NSUserDefaults`, there are limitation on the things that it can save.

Comment: @zaph I understand that that is the case. However, it seems that this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910612/store-cllocationcoordinate2d-to-nsuserdefaults, provides a way in which you can store CLLocationCoordinate2D into NSUserDefaults. I just don't know the translation from Objective C to Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your code to the following

```
let mapAnnotations = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let newCoordinate = self.mapView.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: self.mapView)
let lat = NSNumber(double: newCoordinate.latitude)
let lon = NSNumber(double: newCoordinate.longitude)
let userLocation: NSDictionary = ["lat": lat, "long": lon]
self.mapAnnotations.setObject(userLocation, forKey: "userLocation") //the error is here
self.mapAnnotations.synchronize()
```

What I've done is:

- Create two `NSNumber` objects with the `Double`s and collected them in an `NSDictionary` (and not a Swift `Dictionary`).
- Passed this `NSDictionary` to be saved by your `NSUserDefaults`, which should accept it now, just like the Objective-C code.