# Find distance between two points using MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

i have to find distance between two points **(lat and long)**

```
SELECT *,(3959 * ACOS( COS(RADIANS(".$latitude.")) * COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(longitude) - RADIANS(".$longitude.")) + SIN(RADIANS(".$latitude.")) * SIN(RADIANS(latitude)))) as distance FROM tbl_places tp 
            LEFT JOIN tbl_categories tc 
            ON tp.category_id = tc.category_id
            WHERE tc.category_name = 'food'
            ORDER BY distance ASC
```

Comment: ...and what is your question?

Comment: So, Whats the question ?

Comment: and be careful with those string concatenations.

Comment: this query are not to find distance....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate distance given 2 points, latitude and longitude](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599200/calculate-distance-given-2-points-latitude-and-longitude)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function:

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {
    return ($miles * 1.609344);
  } else if ($unit == "N") {
      return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
      }
}

echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "M") . " Miles<br>";
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "K") . " Kilometers<br>";
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "N") . " Nautical Miles<br>";
```

[Code reference - geodatasource](http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/php)

Comment: Sounds great !!. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helps you :D