# Latitude and Longitude datatype and storage format

Tags: mysql, types, geocoding

I see two formats being used like:
41.45063 N and (N 40°48'27.34").

I assume:
If i use first format then i need only 2 colums: Decimal, Direction
If i use the second format then i need 4 colums: Degree, Minute, Second, Direction

Which format is used to store in the database and how to convert from 1 format to the other. Also are we storing only the cordinates or even the direction like N,S,E,W?

I am using cordinates for local places in MySQL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the ideal data type to use when storing latitude / longitudes in a MySQL database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159255/what-is-the-ideal-data-type-to-use-when-storing-latitude-longitudes-in-a-mysql)

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the second format into the first trivially. There are sixty minutes in a degree, and sixty seconds in a minute. In your example of 40°48′27.34″ it's **40** + (**48** ∙ 60 + **27.34**) / 3600 ≈ 40.807594°.

So you need two columns, one for longitude, one for latitude (you know, you can just encode direction into the sign of the number).

Comment: So i need to convert this at runtime each time users input eitherway or do i need to maintain a lookup table that has this converted in both formarts for quick retrival?

Comment: @RayHT - conversion from decimal to degrees, minutes and seconds is quite easy and computationally cheap so you can do it at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

`40°48'27.34` is simply a floating point number that's been formatted for easier human consumption. Unless your data table had fields for "degrees", "minutes", and "seconds", you can't store that "human" format directly. However, storing it as a single floating point value of `41.45063` lets you reformat it into the human-friendly format on-demand.

There's no need for a direction field. You can assume that positive numbers indicate North and West, and negative numbers indicate South/East.

Comment: Ok of i have a positive number how will i know if it is North or West without some direction flag? And you mean if i have this 45.333333 this is the same as 45 degrees, 33 minutes 33 seconds?

Comment: You'd need to store latitude/longitude  together in seperate fields, of course. Geo coordinates are useless with just one or the other. 45.3333333333 would be 45 degrees and 20 minutes (20/60 = 1/3 = 0.3333)

Comment: North and East are positive, by standard convention.  South and West are negative. Just like Cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

RayHT

The formats you are are referring to are known as decimal format and DMS (Degrees, Minutes, Seconds). There is a straight forward function for converting back-n-forth. Just google 'Degrees to Decimal conversion' for the language your using (PHP, Javascript, etc).

When storing decimal format, the sign of the value indicates direction. For latitude, positive values are North and negative are South. For Longitude, positive values are East and negative values are West.

Here's a link to an online converter and a description of the basics that you might find useful in undertstanding how this works.

http://www.csgnetwork.com/gpscoordconv.html

Andrew
Part of the "OpenGeoCode.Org" Team