# Inserting symbols in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using php and mysql and I have a problem with inserting latitude and longitude values along with the **degree, min and sec symbols.** that is (°,',") symbols.

I have referred several sites and tried different ways but i just can't solve it.

First i tried copying symbols and concatenating with the 3 user input values.

```
$latitude=$degree.'°'.$min.'''.$sec.'?'.'N';
```

Then after executing the insert query,the $latitude variable value is inserted in database, but the symbols are replaced by random characters as shown here.

```
2Ëš3Ê¼4Ë®N (data stored in database)
```

Then i tried using html character code instead of symbols.

```
$latitude=$degree.'&deg'.$min.'&#8217'.$sec.'#8221'.'N';
```

But it doesn't work.It displays the same html characters in databse.

I don't know whether it is a problem with html entities or something.

Comment: You have bad enconding, isn't the same in app and database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function:

```
 $result = mysqli_real_escape_string();
```

refer following link

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion such values should be stored without including its ( `DMS` : Deg Min Sec ) formatting .
In other words , I might store latitude/longitude ( for example ) as a float value and would apply required formatting when displaying .

Just for example :

- You would store a date as `2015-04-23` but might display it as `4th April, 2015` .
- You might store an amount as `10.50` but might display it as `$10.50 USD` .

Coming to latitude/longitude considering `36°19'11.46" N` as example , one of these ways might apply to your situation :

- Store it as `36.31985` but use required conversion to display it as `36°19'11.46" N` .
- Store it as `36D19M11.46S N` but use required string manipulation to display it as `36°19'11.46" N` .
- Store it as four parts `lat_deg` , `lat_min` , `lat_sec` , `lat_dir` but use concatenation to display it as `36°19'11.46" N` .

Links that might help :

[mysql-convert-degree-minutes-seconds-to-degree-decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868228/mysql-convert-degree-minutes-seconds-to-degree-decimal)

[latitude-and-longitude-datatype-and-storage-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722948/latitude-and-longitude-datatype-and-storage-format)

[convert-dd-to-dms-in-mysql](http://assemblysys.com/convert-dd-to-dms-in-mysql/)

[converting-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-between-decimal-and-degrees-minutes-seconds](https://www.dougv.com/2012/03/converting-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-between-decimal-and-degrees-minutes-seconds/)

[whats-the-best-way-to-store-co-ordinates-longitude-latitude-from-google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551894/whats-the-best-way-to-store-co-ordinates-longitude-latitude-from-google-maps)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, i have tried that too and it is working fine, but my clients was it as one attribute in table. There is no further calculation using this data.Just for storing.

Comment: I would also think having it in one column is better but my my advise would be not to include the formatting within possibly . Please check my updated answer .