# Data type to save Latitude and Longitude values in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

I'm saving latitude and longitude values in a MySQL. Right now I'm saving them as Varchar, but I wonder whether I'll be able to make queries for example to get Rows with latitude and longitude in a range so I can get results in a certain radio.

Should I use a different column type to store them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the ideal data type for latitude / longitude?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159255/what-is-the-ideal-data-type-for-latitude-longitude)

Comment: Would this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188197/problem-storing-latitude-and-longitude-values-in-mysql-database answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the precision your application requires, you would select from either [Fixed-Point Types (Exact Value)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html) or [Floating-Point Types (Approximate Value)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use [MySQL Spatial Extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/spatial-extensions.html) and GIS?