# MySQL storing google maps lat/long data

Tags: mysql, google-maps, geolocation, multilinestring

I have created a map which allows the user to plot multiple markers with the intention on storing them in a database table. The original plan was to store multiple rows per one map like so:

```
------------------------------------
| mapentryid | mapid | Long | Lat  | 
------------------------------------
| 1          | 1     | X.XX | X.XX |
| 2          | 1     | X.XX | X.XX |
| 3          | 1     | X.XX | X.XX |
| 4          | 2     | X.XX | X.XX |
| 5          | 2     | X.XX | X.XX |
| 6          | 2     | X.XX | X.XX |
| 7          | 2     | X.XX | X.XX |
------------------------------------
```

But I have since found out that you are able to store [multilinestring](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gis-class-multilinestring.html)'s in MySQL which sounds perfect for what I want (I think?)

I can insert the data correctly using the following SQL query format:

```
INSERT INTO table (LatLng)
VALUES (
         MultiLineString(
            LineString(Point(x),Point(y)),
            LineString(Point(x),Point(y)),LineString(Point(x),Point(y))
       )
```

This adds the multilinestring OK, although they actually come up as the following:

[image: phpmyadmin screenshot]

The question is, is the above OK? If so, how can I convert this data back into something I am able to display on Google Maps?

Comment: Why is it better for you to store the coordinates as mulit-line strings? What if you want to be able to retrieve for instance which users that have stored coordinates near each other, or whatever?

Comment: I suggest you use the following definitions of the fields: `latitude decimal(18,7) DEFAULT NULL` and `longitude decimal(18,7) DEFAULT NULL`

Comment: @Stefan, I just assumed that I should make use of MySQL's built in functions/datatypes?

Comment: @Jelly, I did think that initially but then found these different datatypes which I thought may be interesting to use and perhaps make my life easier..

Comment: Prisoner: It'd probably be much easier to just do selects on rows, than on nested data within strings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the ideal data type to use when storing latitude / longitudes in a MySQL database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159255/what-is-the-ideal-data-type-to-use-when-storing-latitude-longitudes-in-a-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use POINT data?

```
INSERT INTO geoTable (mapentryid, mapid, coord) VALUES (
    1, 1, GeomFromText('POINT(15 20)')
);
```

I always use the ['Well-Known Text (WKT) Format'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/gis-wkt-format.html) for geospatial enabled queries in MySQL, they are the most compatible with other systems out there.

To query the stored values:

```
SELECT mapentryid, mapid, X(coord), Y(coord) FROM geoTable;
```

Comment: Thanks, I went with this in the end!