# How to store lat/long in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, google-maps

I'm working on Google map API. after i choose the start and end point the map return the routed way as a path on the google map,  and i have track the lat/lng from the routed path 
as follows [ the coordinates below are the lat/long of a routed line]

```
13.692941, 100.750723,
13.70649,100.75405999999998,
13.71334,100.75428999999997,
13.72268,100.74638000000004,
13.72775,100.74631,
13.8153,100.73532999999998,
13.81332,100.73160000000007,
```

i want to store all these lat/long in MySQL database. 
i found that there is Spatial extension in MySQL.
and there is a way to insert lat/long as linestring

```
insert into geom (g)
values (GeomFromText('linestring(2 3,7 5,10 10)'))
```

i wanna know how to add all those above lat long into linestring function?
or there is another suggestion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the ideal data type to use when storing latitude / longitudes in a MySQL database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159255/what-is-the-ideal-data-type-to-use-when-storing-latitude-longitudes-in-a-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store these lat/lon DATA like bellow  -

```
$arr = array("13.692941, 100.750723",
"13.70649,100.75405999999998",
"13.71334,100.75428999999997",
"13.72268,100.74638000000004");

// serialize data before save to database, you should deserialized that when you will use this data after query.
$serializedArr = serialize($arr);
insert into geom (g) values ("{$serializedArr}");
```