# MySQL storing Floats

Tags: mysql, floating-point, latitude-longitude

I am trying to save a float number which is this long

> 13.00386644742523

Its basically Lat and Lng value.
when i save it in the database its getting stored as

> 13.0039

Comment: what is the datatype of field? I know its float but what float(?,?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the ideal data type for latitude / longitude?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159255/what-is-the-ideal-data-type-for-latitude-longitude)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on experience I did this for a navigation database built from ARINC424 and eventually used a DECIMAL(18,12) for storing values in radians.

*NOTE*: Floats and doubles aren't as precise and may result in rounding errors

The point is that when using degrees or radians we know the range of the values - and the fractional part needs the most digits.

The best way is to use [MySQL Spatial Extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html)

Comment: how to assign it in PHP Myadmin ?

Comment: enter the following into the SQL window: ALTER TABLE `table-name` CHANGE COLUMN `field-name` `field-name` DECIMAL(18,12) ;

Answer (score 8):

You should use the precision explicitly and the type should be `DECIMAL` **NOT** `FLOAT`
 as every digit after decimal point is significant and you cant let they allow to be changed because of rounding.

```
`lat`  DECIMAL(16,14)
```

Read on [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html)

Comment: that's wrong: Floating-Point Types are Approximate Value in MySQL - which is extremely bad for lat/lon

Answer (score 3):

I think your [data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html) for the the column is defined as `Float(N,4)` where N is the number and 4 is the number of decimal places allowed. That is why it is rounding the stored value.

The best way to store Lat/Long is to use [spatial data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-type-overview.html). POINT geometry type will hold your values

Comment: Link is dead. Here use this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-type-overview.html