# MySql using Float Data Type To Store Geographic Coordinates

Tags: mysql, google-maps, geolocation

I have a table that stores longitude and latitude coordinates (google maps) i have the columns defined as **float** however when i try to insert a value -61.45859899999999 and 10.28289 they are being rounded off to -61.46 and 10.30. How can i modify the columns to hold the data as is.

I am using **mysql toad**. Under is the code for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblGeoCodes` (
  `recNo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `longLocation` float(30,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latLocation` float(30,2) DEFAULT NULL
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the ideal data type to use when storing latitude / longitudes in a MySQL database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159255/what-is-the-ideal-data-type-to-use-when-storing-latitude-longitudes-in-a-mysql)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two problems with your implementation.

The reason the values are both being rounded to 2 digits of precision is that you explicitly defined the scale as 2.

Also, FLOAT is an imprecise data type in MySQL.

To solve both problems you should use the DECIMAL data type with an appropriate precision and scale.

For example, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblGeoCodes` (
  `recNo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  `longLocation` decimal(18,14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latLocation` decimal(18,14) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Example:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `tblGeoCodes` (
    ->   `recNo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    ->   `longLocation` decimal(18,14) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `latLocation` decimal(18,14) DEFAULT NULL
    -> ); 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> insert into tblGeoCodes (longLocation,latLocation) values(-61.45859899999999 , 10.28289);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> select * from tblGeoCodes;
+-------+--------------------+-------------------+
| recNo | longLocation       | latLocation       |
+-------+--------------------+-------------------+
|     1 | -61.45859899999999 | 10.28289000000000 |
+-------+--------------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: i tried this and i am getting -61.45860000000000 when i insert -61.45859899999999 how can i prevent this?

Answer (score 5):

The `,2` in  `float(30,2)` represents 2 decimal places. I use `float(10,6)` as this is adequate to hold coordinates

Comment: Well, six decimal points is about 2 inches at the equator (or any line of longitude), so if that is sufficient accuracy, you're okay with 6 decimal places. It depends for what purpose you're using latitude and longitude.

Comment: As OP is using coordinates in Google Maps and most GPS systems are accurate to about 10 meters, 6 decimal places is adequate

Comment: Overkill, rather than adequate, I would suggest. Four decimal points is 18.3 feet (5.6 m), so you could save some space and some calculation time if you stored 4 instead of 6.

Comment: 10 - 6 = 4, the sign doesn't count (that comes from the (un)signed specification.

Comment: Google themselves recommend 10,6: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest converting to MYISAM to take advantage of [GSI](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html). It is better suited for that purpose and should perform better.

However, as already suggested, increasing precision of float fields might be a simpler solution. Since you're  tagged the question as google-maps releted I'd also recommend [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3) at Google's dev site.

Comment: would i have the float being inserted as is without round the value?

Comment: Perhaps I didn't give the most practical answer. I've edited to more useful (I hope).

Answer (score 0):

Bare in mind that `FLOAT(10,6)` makes no sense, this reserves 4 digits for the integer part.

Personally, I prefer `DOUBLE(9,6)` but you might use `FLOAT` instead to save the 4 extra bytes.