# PHP filter flag and MySQL column type for Google maps coordinates

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, validation

I wonder what is the correct filter flag for using with filter_input() to sanitize the Google map points. I found the `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT` much suitable for using with it. Unfortunately, it removes the decimal point and turn it into the full integer.

```
// Assume map_lng has the value 25.260950449662975
$lng = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'map_lng', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);

// As per above line, $lng will have the value of 25260950449662975
```

I can not see any other suitable format. How could I use the the above flag correctly? Do I need to associate it with any optional options?

And what is the right MySQL Column type and size can be used to `fit` maximum `lat` or lng value returned by Google map API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add another option : `FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION`, for example:

```
$lng = filter_input(
        INPUT_POST, 
        'map_lng', 
        FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT,
        FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION
);
```

More informations [here](http://php.net/manual/fr/filter.filters.flags.php).

For the column type and size, i can only link you [Ike Walker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15886417/3675899), hope it helps.

Comment: I used decimal (20,17) for column type, buy I am not sure any value of Google lat and lng can fit into this.

Comment: In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965166/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-latitude-and-longitude), they suggest using 6 decimals for a 10 cm precision, going further is up to you depending on your need.

Comment: Couldn't find any information on maximum length of lat value from Google, but in previous answer is said that "Any more than 8 decimal places is noise" (@Gilbert Le Blanc).