# Best MySQL data type to store lat/long

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

I have seen several answers but none seem to work ... I need to know the best MySQL data type to store a lat / lon value.  An example lon value returned from the API:

`-75.2408658`

Currently, I have the column set to `Decimal(10,7)`, but this rounds the value to the nearest tenth and stores as such:

`-75.2408660`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Try using mysql spatial extensions

Comment: I've looked into it but I can't seem to figure it out ... what do I need to do on the server side to convert the value to be stored in the DB?

Comment: Keep in mind latitude and longitude with a precision of 4 decimal places is accurate to a scale of inches.

Comment: Well, I don't know why you don't just use `DOUBLE`.  But then again, do you realise that the difference in your two values is approximately 1cm?  Surely not worth getting fussy over.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the ideal data type to use when storing latitude / longitudes in a MySQL database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159255/what-is-the-ideal-data-type-to-use-when-storing-latitude-longitudes-in-a-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

> Use MySQL's spatial extensions with GIS.

Already an SO thread is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159255/what-is-the-ideal-data-type-to-use-when-storing-latitude-longitudes-in-a-mysql) .

[This](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html) also might help you.