# How to query for FLOAT values?

Tags: php, mysql

How do I know if a pair of FLOAT(11,7) primary keys already exists?

I have these values lat: 50.0077953 and lng: -119.3953705

I do:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_geo_mashup_locations WHERE lat = '50.0077953' AND lng = '-119.395367'
```

Since this success, I do,

```
INSERT INTO wp_geo_mashup_locations (lat,lng) VALUES ('50.0077953', '-119.395367')
```

I get:

```
    Duplicate entry '50.0077934--119.3953705' for key 2
```

Comment: Show your actual code.

Comment: maybe INSERT IGNORE is an option for you?

Comment: They're not really floats are they? They're decimals!

Comment: i'm using the type of decimal in the database column and only two numbers after the dot or comma,(well, depends on the situation, but that's in most cases)...

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the INSERT fails, you know the pair already exists.

Alternatively, use some threshold when searching, eg:

```
lat BETWEEN 50.0077953-0.00005 AND 50.0077953+0.00005.
```

Note: you have play with this a bit till you figure out the right threshold (I don't know the resolution needed for long and lat coordinates).

Note: [What is the ideal data type to use when storing latitude / longitudes in a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159255/what-is-the-ideal-data-type-to-use-when-storing-latitude-longitudes-in-a-mysql) - People suggest using spatial extensions, DECIMAL or FLOAT(10,6) / FLOAT(9,6) here.