# How to fetch lat-long stored in mysql and display on google maps in android

Tags: android, mysql, json, google-maps

I am developing an tracking system in android and I have list of latitude and longitude stored in MySQL database. I want to display the stored lat-long on Google maps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the ideal data type to use when storing latitude / longitudes in a MySQL database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159255/what-is-the-ideal-data-type-to-use-when-storing-latitude-longitudes-in-a-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with Google Maps APi v3 [Check here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) the official website .. There is a sample there in the website to start with .
and if you want to get data from MySQL databse check [this link](http://adilmukarram.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/sending-and-receiving-data-from-a-php-web-application/)