# What is the ideal data type to store latitude and longitude values in Python?

Tags: python, types, latitude-longitude

What is the ideal data type to store latitude and longitude values in Python? Take a `stops.txt` in GTFS as an example,

```
stop_lat,stop_lon
48.82694828196076,2.367038433387592
48.82694828196076,2.367038433387592
48.829830695271106,2.376120009344837
48.829830695271106,2.376120009344837
48.83331371557845,2.387299704383512
48.83331371557845,2.387299704383512
48.840542782965464,2.3794094631230687
48.840542782965464,2.3794094631230687
48.844652150982945,2.37310814754528
```

Corresponding to [What is the ideal data type to use when storing latitude / longitudes in a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159255/what-is-the-ideal-data-type-to-use-when-storing-latitude-longitudes-in-a-mysql) and the highly upvoted answer is:

> Use MySQL's spatial extensions with GIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) is the way to go, easy accessing by name, and used like tuple(for the precision use float):

```
In[4]: from collections import namedtuple
In[5]: coords = namedtuple("Coords", ['x', 'y'])
In[6]: coords
Out[6]: __main__.Coords
In[7]: coords(1,2)
Out[7]: Coords(x=1, y=2)
In[8]: coords(1.235445,2.2345345)
Out[8]: Coords(x=1.235445, y=2.2345345)
In[9]: coords(1.2354451241234214,2.234534512412414134)
Out[9]: Coords(x=1.2354451241234214, y=2.2345345124124143)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you need 6 decimal places. So, float would hold your data. Or decimal with precision set to 6?

Answer (score 1):

you can define FLOAT(N,D) where default is (10,2) where 2 is the number of decimals and 10 is the total number of digits including decimals, decimal precisions can go up to 24 places for float and 53 places for DOUBLE(N,D).

Answer (score 0):

You've asked to store latitude and longitude and jugdging by the amount of data you are going to store, I would go for a list of tuples of floats:

```
data = [
    (48.82694828196076,2.367038433387592),
    (48.82694828196076,2.367038433387592)
]
```

The tuple can - of course - be replaced by a list at any point. Especially since it only stores 2 floats, the access to it is not that costly, you won't really notice the difference at all. This would then yield to a nested list:

```
data = [
    [48.82694828196076,2.367038433387592],
    [48.82694828196076,2.367038433387592]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's enough to use decimal field here with (18,15), where 18 is total length and 15 is the decimal count of a lat/lng value. 15 + 3 = 18.

```
lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=15, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
lon = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=15, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: 9 decimal places would be accurate to a grain of sand - 15 may be overkill. https://xkcd.com/2170/